Looking for Map2Geo alternative to share location data between Android apps
It is unnecessarily difficult to share geo data between apps in Android. Pick a location in one app and share it with your navigation app? Nope. Park the car in maps and send the location to your smart watch? Nope. Apart from a few exceptions, it is all just impossible.
I don't know if it's by design to keep you from using a competitors app, or if there is just no good standard for geo data in Android and few apps ended up using the same format, but I needed some 3rd party app to convert the geo data for me. I used Map2Geo (catfish.android.map2geo) plus the 'url injector' (catfish.android.map2geo.urlinjector) by Catfish for that. For a while life was uncomplicated. Someone could send me a message with a Google Maps location url and I could simply choose to open it in OsmAnd or Flitsmeister. Then, Map2Geo got removed from the Play Store and I cannot install it on my new phone. There is a mirror with the original description, but I can only assume it was removed from the Play Store with good reason. Although the app appears safe, I can't trust third parties. Better safe than sorry.
Now I have become increasingly frustrated not being able to do simple things that I know are technically possible. If someone sends me a link from their favorite location app, I have to open that specific app or their specific website in stead of my favorite app. I have searched everywhere for an alternative. I can't even find others asking the same question. Am I missing something? Is there a similar tool on a trusted source that does the conversion between apps locally, and not on some service that may sell your geo data?
I previously asked this on Android Stack Exchange but was recommended to ask here in stead.

Maybe OpenDefault can help you there? If I understand correctly, you could let it open e.g. links to Google Maps with OSMAnd (or Organic Maps, or whatever other map application). Easy Open Link would be another candidate for that. Both are not limited to locations, of course.

Also on Android.SE: Looking for way to share location data between apps

Today I had the same question.
I found this alternative:
https://github.com/jakubvalenta/geoshare
To make it work more efficiently I recommend to change the following:
In Android

Settings - Apps - Default apps - Opening links - Geo Share
Tick "Open supported links" and check all options.

In Firefox

Settings - Open links in apps
Set it to always or ask before opening

